# How to print content of RichTextBox with multiple font type using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I want to print `RichTextBox` content which contains multiple font type in C#

Comment: It is possible using rich text format, but quite complicated I believe...

Comment: RTB does not support DrawToBitmap. But maybe zooming it and then taking a screenshot at a high resolution could workaround. Or embed a WPF solution..

Comment: Have  a look [at this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812425)

Comment: can you show some work you've done for this?

Answer (score 0):

In wpf app you can do like this

```
        var printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)myRichTextBox.Document).DocumentPaginator;
            printDlg.PrintDocument(paginator, "Printing");
        }
```

Comment: Actually I am using C# Window application.

Answer (score 0):

First save the content in rtf format type. Second convert to docs and print file.